# What ways can I double-check my binary calculations?

Tags: binary

I need help checking the result of these calculations.

I went to some binary calculator website and they gave me different answers
even though I did it manually and it seems like the result is right.

> 1000 1111 + 1111 1001 = 1 1000 1000, no under/overflow, 392
>
> 1000 1111 + 1011 1001 = 1 0100 1000, no under/overflow, 328
>
> 1111 1111 - 1111 1001 = 0000 0110, no under/overflow, 6
>
> 1011 1111 - 0111 1001 = 0100 0110, no under/overflow, 70
>
> 0011 1111 - 1111 1001 = 0100 0110, underflow, 70

Comment: Are you running on Windows? Windows Calculator (Calc.exe) has a programmers mode which will let you check this yourself. The one on Windows 10 is especially good at letting you enter/do math in one base and displaying values in three others at the same time.

Comment: There are a lot of web calculators... try https://www.google.com/?q=binary%20calculator%20online

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unlikely to be useful for future readers.